# C++ Broken Program - WPRFLAG?

Tags: c++, error-handling

I am working on creating a program for class where we were supposed to have it take a list of grades (up to 100 grades), sort them, and output the mean and median as well as a list of the grades with 5 grades per line. I have my code finished, it builds and starts running, but exits with no output. single stepping through to find the error, it gets to a point where it jumps to a WPRFLAG line in another file called crtexe.c. I wanted to post my code and see if anyone could help point me in the right direction. Right now, I do not know what this wprflag is nor do I see why my code is just exiting.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include<cmath>
#include<iomanip>
#include<sstream>
using namespace std;
inline void keep_window_open() { char ch; cin>>ch; }
///////////////////////////////Function Prototypes///////////////////////////////
double mean (int[], int);
double median (int[], int);
///////////////////////////////Main//////////////////////////////////////////////
//Main takes input for up to 100 grades and stores in an array then calls the 
//mean and median functions for those calculations then outputs the mean, median,
//and list of grades sorted low to high with 5 grades per line
//Main takes input in as a string and coverts to int. This is to allow user to 
//enter EXIT to end the input loop. There is some error checking built in so 
//use can only enter 0-100 or exit. 
int main ()
{
int counter=0, valueInt=0, numberGrades=0;                      
//counter is used to limit loop to 100 cycles and indicate which element in 
//array to store valueInt
int grades [100] = {0};                 
string valueString=" ";
cout<<"Use this program to calculate the Mean and Median of up to 100 ";
cout<<"grades.\n**Please enter positive real whole numbers only ";
cout<<"(0-100).\n";
do                                              //main input loop
{
    cout<<"Key in a grade and press [Enter] or type EXIT to end list\n";
    cin>>valueString;
        if (valueString=="exit"||valueString=="EXIT"||valueString=="Exit")
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            stringstream convert(valueString);  //converts String to Int
            if (!(convert>>valueInt))           //for array
            {                                   
                valueInt=0;                     
            }                                   

            if (cin.fail())                     //error checking for any 
            {                                   //text input that is not
                cin.clear();                    //"exit"
                cin.ignore(1000,'\n');                  
                cout<<"Incorrect input. Try again\n";
                break;
            }
            if (valueInt<0||valueInt>100)       //error checking for 
            {                                   //0>valueInt>100
                cout<<"Grades can only be 0-100. Please try again.\n";
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                grades[counter]=valueInt;       //Actual input into array
                numberGrades++;
                counter++;
            }
        }
}
while (counter<100);
cout<<"The average grade point is "<<mean(grades, numberGrades)<<".\n";
cout <<"The median grade point is "<<median(grades, numberGrades)<<".\n";

for (int outer=0;outer<numberGrades;outer++)            //sorting loop
{
    for (int inner=0;inner<numberGrades-1;inner++)
    {
        if  (grades[inner]>grades[inner+1])
        {
            swap(grades[inner], grades[inner+1]);
        }
    }
}

counter=0;
for (int i=0;i<counter;i++)                             //print list loop
{
    cout<<grades[counter]<<" ";
    counter++;
    if (i==4)
    {
        cout<<"\n";
    }



                //The next two lines stop the Command Prompt window from 
                //closing until the user presses a key, including Enter.
                cout    << "\nPress enter twice to exit." << endl;
                                                    cin.ignore(2);
}
}
///////////////////////////////Mean//////////////////////////////////////////////
//Mean() finds the averge of the list of grades stored in the grades array and 
//returns that value to the cout statement in main(). 
double mean (int grades[], int numberGrades)
{
double total=0.0;
for (int counter=0;counter<numberGrades+1;counter++)
{
    total+=grades[counter];
}
total=total/numberGrades;
return (total);
}

///////////////////////////////Median////////////////////////////////////////////
//Median() first sorts the values stored in the grades array then finds the 
//median value. If numberGrades is odd value, will show the middle value of the 
//sorted array list. If numberGrades is an even value, will display the average
//of the two middle values in the sorted array list.
double median (int grades[], int numberGrades)              
{
double total=0.0;
for (int outer=0;outer<numberGrades;outer++)            //sorting loop
{
    for (int inner=0;inner<numberGrades-1;inner++)
    {
        if  (grades[inner]>grades[inner+1])
        {
            swap(grades[inner], grades[inner+1]);
        }
    }
}

if (numberGrades%2==0)
{
    total=((grades[numberGrades/2]+grades[numberGrades/2-1])/2);
}
else
{
    total=grades[numberGrades/2];
}
return (total);

}
```

Just wanted to say thank you for any time put into this. All responses are very much appreciated! I will try to update this if I find an answer.

Comment: Are you sure about this condition: `counter<numberGrades+1`? I'd suspect you're reading out of bounds.

Comment: Try stepping over instead of stepping in, especially when using standard library functions.

Comment: without really looking at your code, I copy&pasted this into my visual studio environment and it looks as if it works just fine. Any specific input to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Same here. Tried with g++. Didn't look at the code. Seemed to work. (I didn't check if the computed results where actually correct)

Comment: for input, i either typed 1-100 as the first 100 grades or 1-20 (1...2...3..4...55..56..99..100 or 1..2..3..19..20..exit). I wasn't expecting such quick replies. Thank you!

Comment: For counter<numberGrade+1, I assume you are referring to the for loop in the mean function. If my understanding is correct, that allows the condition to see the numberGrades variable and limit the loop to less than that variable. If less than 1+numberGrades then loop.

Comment: Actually, I think I may have found my mistake. It is a silly one. The lines to keep console open were within the final for loop in main(). moved those lines out of the for loop and the windows stays open for me to see the output. Moving on now. Thank you all for your help. Sorry to have wasted your time over a silly mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Moved the below lines out of the final for loop in the main function. This let the console stay open to show output.

Program was working correctly as coded. My output was not correct due to logic error.

```
//The next two lines stop the Command Prompt window from 
//closing until the user presses a key, including Enter.
cout    << "\nPress enter twice to exit." << endl;
cin.ignore(2);
```